# How to force some applications to use second network in Network->Service order?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

My computer is connected to 2 networks, first via ethernet, and second via USB WiFi.

In the first network there is no internet, there are only local applications that I need to use for my work and local sites.

When I want to internet access I change networks order to USB WiFi first but then I loose contact to local sites and applications.

Is there any way to tell a program, for example Google Chrome, to use only second network and all other applications use the first network?

Answer (score 2):

Best route to take (pun intended) is to setup routing, so your computer know what interface to choose to contact to network in question..

So your default gateway should only be set to the gw on your internet-facing network. The internal network should not have a gateway specified. You should manually specify all the subnets you need to reach and use whatever gw you have on the other network.

It's kind of hard to give more detailed information without knowing more about the environment.. Like how many subnets you need to reach on the interface that isn't connected to the internet. If there is only one, you shouldn't need to do anything, since it doesn't require it.

I also assume that you don't use the same IP-ranges on both networks..

Answer (score -1):

You cant do this with Windows natively.  You need a 3rd part application.  [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) will do this.  Here are some good [directions](https://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/).

Comment: Thank you, but I need for macos.

Comment: @Narek-T then you should put that in your question

Comment: I already have macos in tags ;) And before edit title of question was "os x - How to force some applications to use second network in Network->Service order?"